# Compare two sentences sequence wise

Tags: php, matching, string-comparison, string-matching

The scenario is there is a given sentence. The user have to type in the sentence in some input field and that will be saved to database.
Now, I want to compare both the sentences and find out, how many words the user has typed in correctly and incorrectly (missed any word, or added some new words by typing mistake).
Now I have done something like this-

```
$Str1 = "i **am** suraj roy i **am** having my lunch";
$Str2 = "i suraj roy i **am** having my dinner";

$st1 = (explode(" ", $Str1));
$st2 = (explode(" ", $Str2));

$result1 = array_diff($st1, $st2);
$result2 = array_diff($st2, $st1);

$word_count1 = count($result1); // words not present in typed sentence from original sentence - lunch
$word_count2 = count($result2); // newly added words in typed sentence - dinner

$total_error_count = $word_count1 + $word_count2;

echo 'Total words not matching between two sentences - '.$total_error_count;
```

Now this is working as i expected. Good.

But the problem is, have a look at the word **am** in both sentences, as the comparison is being done between array its taking single occurrence of **am** in typed sentence for all the occurrence of **am** in original sentence. So, there is no missing word count for **am** in typed sentence.

So, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Str2 is typed. current output is 2, as one word missing form original sentence, and one word is added newly. But output should be 3, as there is 'am' missing after 'I' in typed sentence which Str2.

Comment: its basically for a type test application which i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Wouldn't information about the kind of difference, as from `diff <(tr \  \\n <<<"i **am** suraj roy i **am** having my lunch") <(tr \  \\n <<<"i suraj roy i **am** having my dinner")`, be more useful than just the count? Anyway, the PHP array diff functions don't provide what you wish. Do you require a PHP solution?

Comment: What if the order of two words was exchanged?

Comment: @Armali yes, i need a php solution.

Comment: In your _EXAMPLE - I WILL GO TO SCHOOL AT 10 AM, IF USER TYPED - I AM GO TO SCHOOL AM 10. SO OUTPUT ERROR COUNT SHOULD BE --- 6_ - why 6? _WILL|AM_ give 2, _AT|AM_ give 2, _AM_ gives 1, makes 5, doesn't it?

Comment: @Armalisorry.. typing mistake .. Original- I WILL GO TO SCHOOL AT 10 AM, IF USER TYPED - I AM GO TO SCHOOL AT AM 10 --- So, WILL / AM - 2, 10 / AM - 2, AM - 10 - 2 ... So, it's 6

Comment: I can't make sense of your requirement for `10 AM` vs. `AM 10` to make 4; an algorithm which looks for insertions and deletions would detect an insertion of `AM`, equality of `10` and deletion of `AM`, giving 2. Insisting on getting 4 complicates the matter.

Comment: @Armali basically if user types AM 10 instead of 10 AM ... my requirement is to count this as an error (because meaning has changed), now the point is how many error should it count for this mistake ? So, think like this --- if user types 1)AM 2)10 instead of 3)10 4)AM, so one error is user typed 1)AM instead of 3)10 -- that means he missed 3)10 so 1 error , again as he typed 1)AM it's assumed he added this new word on the position of 3)10 so 1 error ,, for for this 2 error .. and so on .. next user typed 10 in position of AM .. for this another 2 .. so in total 4 ..

Comment: in other way .. your logic is also correct .. so now it depends on what my boss wants ... what he wants he wants ... cheers

Comment: I could only offer a solution in my logic - if your boss doesn't want that, so be it. :-)

Comment: @Armali I really appreciate your help, thanks. I have solved this using   $diff_array = array_diff_assoc($sting2, $sting1);